# Keycloak token exchange with using id_token

Tags: authentication, jwt, token, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm trying to implement token exchange using ID token but I can't get it to work.

I filled the form with followin params:

```
client_id,
client_secret,
grant_type : urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange,
subject_token: already generated id_token
subject_token_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:id_token
```

But I get error:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "Invalid token type, must be access token"
}
```

Which is kinda weird as I specify the type of token to "id_token".
Is there something I am doing wrong or it is just not possible to refresh tokens by ID token while using Keycloak? But looking at docs this should be possible. Token exchange using access token does work.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to exchange the id_token for an access_token. The documentation mentions that your subject_token should be access_token or token from other provider. https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_token-exchange
Could you point to the document which you are referring to ?